# how to delete a line containg string from file in unix or solaris

Tags: shell, unix, sed, solaris

I have myfile as follows

```
test1    
test2    
test3    
test4    
test5
```

I want to delete line containing test2, so I used command as follows, but instead of removing only 'test2' line its removed whole file and fize-size became zero.

```
bash# cat /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile | sed -e '/test2/ d'  > /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile     
bash# ls -l total 0    
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root           0  3月 11 17:41 myfile
```

can anybody suggest , whats wrong in command?

Comment: I'm assuming the first `>` is a typo. The redirection to the file `> /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile` happens before the file is piped into `sed` so the files gets truncated and `cat` then reads an empty file. Use a temporary file as shown in Venky's answer.

Comment: yes first > was typo, edited. any suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 7):

unless you have GNU sed (with the "-i" option), and you're on Solaris so you probably don't, you have no choice but to write to temp file:

```
sed -e '.....' infile > infile.tmp
mv infile.tmp infile
```

---

update: edit the file in-place with `ed`

```
printf "%s\n" 'g/test2/d' w q | ed infile
```

Comment: "ed" can do the job even without Gnu sed.

Comment: Then feel free to vote up my answer. Your ed code is bogus. That should be [ printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" 'g/test2/d' w q | ed infile ] or simply [ printf "%s\nw\nq\n" 'g/test2/d' | ed infile ].

Comment: no, the bash builtin printf will reuse the format string as required to consume all the arguments. you might want to tone down the attitude a notch.

Comment: Apologies for my tone/attitude which was unintentional. I'm afraid your answer is still non functional with Solaris ed. The issue isn't with the format reuse which works with Solaris printf command too, but with the compound "wq" which works with Gnu ed but not the SVR4/Solaris one.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if perl is standard on Solaris. If this is the case, you can use:

```
perl -ni -e 'if(!/test2/){print;}' myfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the output redirection immediately empties the output file. Therefore you have to use a different file as output file, eg:

```
sed '/test2/d' /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile > /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile2
```

Or you could do e.g. something like that:

```
sed '/test2/d' /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile | tee /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile
```

But due to buffering this is not very reliable. If the output program (`tee`) writes to the file before sed has finished reading, this will lead to corrupt data.
Maybe you could also experiment with the programs `buffer` or `mbuffer` as substitute for `tee` there you can specify buffer sizes. But I didn't have reliable success on a fast trial.

Comment: sry but I have not satisfied with this answer as you said its not reliable :(

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
grep -v test2 test.txt  > temp
mv temp test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the good old ed:

```
echo "/test2
d
w
q" | ed /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `grep`:

```
> grep -v test2 test.txt 
test1    
test3    
test4    
test5
```

Be aware that as with `sed`, you shouldn't overwrite the file you are reading from, so you can invoke it like this:

> grep -v test2 test.txt > test.out

Comment: Its just display output without test2 but actual test.txt is not updated!

Answer (score 1):

Solaris, assuming you are not on an archaic version, should already come with at least bash 3. So using just bash

```
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
     *"test2"*) continue;;
     *) echo "$line";;   
  esac
done < file > temp && mv temp file
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code is workign fine for me...

```
touch myfile2
cp /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile myfile2
sed '/test2/d' myfile2 > /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile
```

Comment: There's no need to `touch` the file first.

Comment: I really don't want the involvement of second file.. can I do it with only myfile alone?? also in one line shell command??

Comment: will this work? <br> sed '/test2/d' myfile > /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile

Comment: @Rupali, I suggest try it yourself and then paste the errors if you recieve any.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole file into an array in AWK:

```
awk '!/test2/ {a[++c] = $0} END {for (i=1; i<=c; i++) print a[i] > FILENAME}' /aaa/bbb/ccc/myfile
```

Since redirection is not done by the shell, early truncation is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$touch myfile

$printf "test1\ntest2\ntest3\ntest4\ntest5\n">myfile

$cat myfile 

test1
test2
test3
test4
test5

$sed '2d' myfile

test1
test3
test4
test5
```

So use:

```
$sed '2d' myfile
```